# Auto adjust div heights with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not much of a javascript person so I am a little lost if what I have done is ok.

I have 3 columns of divs that contain dynamic content and differing numbers of child divs.

I wish to dynamically resize the height so they are all the same height as the tallest column and any difference is distributed evenly amongst the divs in each shorter column. Here is an image of what I mean:

[image]

I have hacked together some very ugly js that seems to work... but looks horrible. Is there a better way to do this that someone can suggest? It also seems a little sluggish on load, is there a way to make it faster?

```
   myHeightTest = function(container){
    var listOFHeights = new Array(),
        tallestContainer = 0;
    $(container).each(function(){
      listOFHeights.push($(this).height());
    });

    //Get the tallest
    tallestContainer = Math.max.apply(null,listOFHeights);

    //check I can calculate the hieght
    console.log('tallest: ' + tallestContainer);

    adjustChildHeights = function(parent,height) {
      var countKids = 0;
      $(parent.children('.flex-item')).each(function(){
        countKids += 1;
      });
      var offset = (height/countKids);
      $(parent.children('.flex-item')).each(function(){
        $(this).css('min-height',$(this).height() + offset);
      });
    }
    //now loop through and adjust
    $(container).each(function(){
      adjustChildHeights($(this),(tallestContainer - $(this).height()));
    });

  }

    $(window).load(function() {
  myHeightTest('.myflex-col');
    });


    $(window).resize(function(){
  myHeightTest('.myflex-col');
    });
```

Comment: Hey could you post your HTML and CSS in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question I think you can easily accomplish this with just CSS using flexbox, no need for any fancy javascript here. Here is an example (I haven't done any padding or margins so it's a bit ugly but I think it'll give you the idea.

```
<div id="outside">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="child">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin dignissim iaculis orci eget malesuada. Quisque auctor orci ipsum, in ornare felis volutpat ut. Integer nec laoreet ex. Sed nec feugiat erat. Vestibulum vel suscipit dui. Aenean ultricies feugiat pulvinar. Donec eu luctus lorem. Integer dapibus dolor nibh, nec aliquet velit dapibus a. Nulla accumsan, sapien eu scelerisque convallis, ligula est lobortis libero, at tincidunt justo ligula maximus elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <p>Sed aliquam est hendrerit mattis vestibulum. Aliquam consectetur, sapien ut placerat ullamcorper, risus orci malesuada dolor, eu consequat eros arcu a risus. Ut congue condimentum nisi nec dignissim. Sed laoreet purus orci, sit amet vestibulum metus tempus quis. Vestibulum facilisis nibh nisl. Aenean semper pharetra sem eu ultricies. Curabitur ut velit tortor. Aliquam vel metus consectetur ante suscipit rutrum. Duis volutpat hendrerit augue, vitae pretium orci laoreet vel.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
           <p>In varius dapibus felis, placerat ultricies diam condimentum id. Phasellus lobortis purus tellus, at faucibus mauris varius vitae. Vestibulum vitae lectus lectus. Praesent ut diam vitae odio tincidunt porttitor sagittis sed ipsum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer scelerisque scelerisque tincidunt. Curabitur et magna pulvinar, auctor est eget, semper nisl.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="child">
            <p>Pellentesque et euismod mi. Nulla id ipsum convallis lacus eleifend vehicula quis id velit. In quis tempus sem, at vulputate nisi. Aenean sit amet tempor massa. Nunc et pulvinar mauris. Nunc pellentesque leo eget massa auctor tempor. Fusce nibh magna, iaculis at massa vel, consequat sagittis nisi.
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <p>Curabitur nec placerat ligula, sed vehicula urna. Aliquam eget convallis lacus. Aenean et lacus eu ligula mollis ornare. Proin sit amet dolor eu dolor suscipit malesuada id sed urna. Integer quam ligula, semper ac elementum a, sollicitudin non turpis. Donec varius ullamcorper lacinia. Donec placerat rutrum nulla quis porta. Aenean auctor, lorem nec elementum semper, odio leo congue enim, lobortis molestie turpis dui quis leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec nibh ante, ornare ac sapien nec, aliquet sagittis diam. Proin id pellentesque ipsum. Aenean sollicitudin condimentum metus, quis pellentesque mauris vehicula vitae. In non venenatis nulla, eget consequat arcu.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="child">
            <p>Etiam libero magna, imperdiet sit amet tincidunt eget, tristique a mi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi aliquet purus id sagittis vulputate. Phasellus dignissim egestas augue aliquet venenatis. Duis condimentum massa odio, at congue purus suscipit eget. Ut sit amet neque eget felis pretium tempus. Fusce imperdiet, ipsum quis ultrices sagittis, lorem diam mollis nisi, eget tempus nisi eros at ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla iaculis sed arcu hendrerit elementum. Aenean vel mi ut sapien posuere vulputate at ut tellus. Nunc convallis, justo et placerat dictum, libero eros scelerisque dolor, eu lacinia metus magna eu tellus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <p>Smaller one for testing</p>
        </div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child">
            <p>other small one</p>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <p>Here is something that I wrote that is not horribly long but still ong enough so you get the picture I image</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#outside {
    display: flex;
}
.column {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;

}
.child {
    background-color: aqua;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Make the surrounding container for the columns `display:flex` and also make each column a column flex. Then by setting the column items to `flex-grow: 1` The will all end up taking up the whole column.

If you really needed to do this using javascript you should just be able to add this CSS to the DOM elements.

Comment: I neglected to mention I need to target some older browsers like IE9 so Flexbox isn't really an option.